# How to hide an element in Wordpress's TinyMCE image editor dialog with jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, image, tinymce

I am trying to hide the Alignment radio buttons for images uploaded to the post content area, but can't figure out how to add a custom CSS or JS file to the Wordpress Image Editor dialog.

[image]

It looks like the dialog box is a TinyMCEPopup which is rendered by an [HTML file](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/3.7.1/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpeditimage/editimage.html), and I can't figure out how to manipulate anything in the .mceWrapper with jQuery. I'm currently hooking into `admin_enqueue_scripts` to load the JS below:

```
    $('.mceWrapper iframe').load( function() {
        $(this).contents().find('tr.align').hide();
    });
```

Comment: I'm afraid that only some advanced JavaScript will be able to handle this. The popup is [rendered by an HTML file](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/3.7.1/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpeditimage/editimage.html) (ie, no hooks). I tried to apply a general CSS in the admin, but the iframe doesn't catches that.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction? I'm currently hooking into admin_enqueue_scripts to load my JS, and am using the code snippet above, but I'm unable to manipulate anything in the .mceWrapper

Comment: Sorry, out of my league... But if you re-tag this with jQuery+JavaScript **and** add a bit more of context, the folks who follow those tags (and they are many and very good) will be able to jump in.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked on wordpress this image plugin , but let me show you how to handle any elements in pop up window of tinymce

all windows pop-up are containing window instances which are added in windows variable of tinymce.windowManager namespace

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.windows
```

will give you all windows that are popped up..in your case only one window is there so

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.windows[0].getEl(0)
```

, getEl method gives you main element in popup window

wire up this element with jquery , using find method find element you want and hide it.

for e.g. go to [tinymce.com](http://tinymce.com) => open any window like insert video or insert image and run this line in console it will hide all container element..

```
$(tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.windows[0].getEl(0))
.find('div.mce-container-body').hide();
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely helpful and a step in the right direction. Unfortunately I'm still having trouble accessing the popup window in Wordpress. tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.windows[0] returns an undefined error, though tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.windows returns an object, but only when the window is open. I tried to wrap it in jQuery load() to detect when the window pops up, but I'm still unable to hide any elements within the tinymce window.

Comment: **but only when the window is open.** , that's your question that whenever i open window i want to hide certain elements..** I tried to wrap it in jQuery load() ** , load is not used for wiring javascript object to jQuery...